# How to append JS dynamic dropdown selections to a google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using a google script html form to captures variables, including pics.  The answers are appended to a google sheet row.  I have altered my form to use a javascript dropdown selection based on the answer given in a previous question.   The problem is that the secondary selection won't append.  What tag should I be using to append the row with?

Comment: Hi, showing us some code would help us help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var DropDown = document.getElementById('DropDownID');
var NewValues = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"];
var NewOption = "";
for(var i=0; i<NewValues.length; i++)
        {
        NewOption = NewOption + "<option value='" + NewValues[i] + "'>" + NewValues[i] + "</option>";
        }
DropDown.innerHTML = NewOption ;
```

Based on the answers of the previous question you need to put this inside a switch statement.